# Anyway to use IN operator in the SELECT statement? If not, why?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

This may come off as a feature request more than anything, but it would be nice if SQL allowed use of the `IN` operator in a `select` statement such as the one below. I want to create `new_variable` in`table1`based on the `ID` variable in `table2`, hence the `case` statement.

```
select ID,
case when ID in (select ID
                 from table2)
     then 1
     else 0
     end as new_variable

from table1
```

I understand that SQL will give me an error if I run this, but why is that the case? It doesn't seem obvious to me why SQL developers couldn't enable the `IN` operator to be used outside of the `WHERE` clause.

Side note: I'm currently using a left join to avoid this issue, so I am not hung up on this.

```
select ID,
       case when ifnull(b.ID, 0) = 0 then 0 
            else 1 
            end as variable_name

from table1

left join(select ID from table2) as b
on a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL definitely supports this:

```
select ID,
       (case when ID in (select ID from table2)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as new_variable
from table1
```

Note that there is a comma after `id`.

This is standard SQL.  If your database doesn't support it, it is a feature request (and one that all or almost all databases support).

Comment: Oh so it may be a database limitation. I wouldn't have known. Edited the first comma in

Comment: What is the point of the parentheses surrounding the case statement? Why is it even needed? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @InfiniteFlash . . . For me, it is a visual clue on where the expression begins and ends.  I tend to wrap most expressions in parentheses unless they are trivial.

Comment: Spark SQL does not support this (least not my version). You'll get an error like `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it. @Andrew